# Android Studio fails to build an APK with DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: android

When I run my project in my phone or in the emulator, it works fine. However, when I try to build the APK, it raises an error.

> Error: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.atm_locator.cbe.cbeatmlocator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { debug { res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res', 'src/debug/res/html'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'
    compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: clean and build Project

Comment: you reached 64k methods limit so need to configure your app as multidex

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: @sasikumar I did that many times but not working.

Comment: @ADM I did that too but it gives me another error.

Comment: You have to enable `Multidex` . Why are using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'` . I think You can use separate  dependency for each google service . Apart from that add the error you are getting after enabling `Multidex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that you've reached the method count limit in Android. This can be solved two ways: Either you start removing dependencies or you enable multidexing. The latter can be enabled the following way:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

On Android API level >= 21 you don't need the compile dependency, as this is supported natively by ART.

You can read all about this on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

For release, I'd suggest to enable proGuard to optimize your app and automatically remove not needed code. For debug builds, to simplify debugging, as mentioned above, you can enable multidex.

For proguard, read documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code - configuration may be not straightforward